# How to insert multiple data with one form submission [ LARAVEL - Eloquent ]

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have form where I am planning to insert data into units table .. it has fields course_id | unit_number | unit_title

relationship defined : course has many units .. units belongs to course.

the form is working fine, in case I'm inserting only one unit. but when I insert multiple rows it only stores the last row.

```
@include('admin.messages')
<form action="{{ route('adminSendCreateUnits')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{{csrf_field()}}
<div  class="row col-12">
<div class="col-sm">
<div class="form-group">

<label style="width:100%; background-color:grey; color:white; padding:15px;" for="course_id">Course</label>
<select name="course_id" class="form-control">
<option>Select Course</option><!--selected by default-->
@foreach ($courses as $course)
<option value="{{$course->id}}"> 
{{ $course->id}}-{{ $course->crs_title}}
</option>
@endforeach
</select>

</div>
</div>
</div><br>

<label for="unit_number">Unit Number</label>
 <select name="unit_number[]" class="form-control">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
</select>

 <label for="unit_title">Unit Title</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="unit_title[]" id="unit_title" placeholder="Unit Title" required>
```

my unitscontroller.php [ I'm sure this is wrong .. since I was trying stuff and i lack the knowledge]

```
 public function adminSendCreateUnit(Request $request){


        $course_id =  $request->input('course_id');
        $unit_number =  $request->input('unit_number', []);
        $unit_title =  $request->input('unit_title', []);
        
       
        $newCategoryArray = array(
                            
                            "course_id"=>$course_id, 
                             "unit_number"=>$unit_number,
                             'created_at' => \Carbon::now(),
                             "unit_title"=> $unit_title);

        $created = DB::table("units")->insert($newCategoryArray);


        if($created){
            return redirect()->route("adminAllUnits")->withSuccess('Unit Created successfully!');
        }else{
           return "Unit was not Created";
        }
}
```

I would like to have the course ID same in all rows .. only Unit number and titles change. would appreciate any input :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved by trying this out.

```
public function adminSendCreateUnit(Request $request){
        $course_id =  $request->input('course_id');
        $unit_number =  $request->input('unit_number', []);
        $unit_title =  $request->input('unit_title', []);
     
        $units = [];

        foreach ($unit_number as $index => $unit) {$units[] = [
                "course_id" => $course_id, // change this
                "unit_number" => $unit_number[$index],
                'created_at' => \Carbon::now(),
                "unit_title" => $unit_title[$index]
            ];
        }
        
        $created = Unit::insert($units);
        
        if($created){
            return redirect()->route("adminAllUnits")->withSuccess('Unit Created successfully!');
        }else{
           return "Unit was not Created";
        }
}
```